# css calc - round down with two decimal cases

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

I have the following situation:

```
div {
    width: calc((100% / 11) - 9.09px);
}
```

In the context, `100%` = `1440px`, and `9.09px` is generated in mathematics with sass.

The results is: `94.55px`, because *`calc`* rounds it **up**, but I need `94.54px` (round **down**).

How can I ***round down*** to the nearest hundredths place?

## Edit: [example](http://codepen.io/cleitonsouza/pen/pbgxgX).

Comment: You shouldn't be getting either of those values. (1440 / 11) = 130.90909px, minus 9.09px = 121.89109px. Can you please create an [MCVE] that reproduces your error?

Comment: But by spec, CSS `calc()` rounds up. So if you want to round down you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @TylerH, example in question body now

Comment: [W3C official discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2513) - *"Add round()/floor()/ceil() functions"* - **please thump it up**

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63667411/8620333

Answer (score 225):

In general I would say that it's not possible, but there's a hack. However in the web, hacks seem to be the norm, instead of the exception, so I'll just say that it is possible:

```
div {
    --shf: 4.9406564584124654e-322;
    width: calc(((100% / 11) - 9.09px) * var(--shf) / var(--shf));
}
```

What this does: it multiplies the value to be rounded by a really small value that underflows the value starting at the third decimal point. Then, it divides the truncated value back, resulting in a rounded version of the value. This assumes that all browsers you support use 64-bit floating point values. If they don't, not only this will be wrong, it might return zero when using smaller floating point data types, completely breaking your page.

Change the exponent to -323 to round at the first decimal point and -324 to round at integer values.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come up with that number specifically for `--shf`?

Comment: @DanielEinars It is the value of the minimum subnormal positive double (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples)

Comment: Your upvotes are coming from https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/k0yj3k/how_to_round_down_numbers_in_css/

Comment: @PhilippWilhelm party-pooper, let him scratch his head for a while =P

Comment: unfortunately it does not work with calc(100vw / 3)

Comment: This is a really cool thing to be aware of. Can ceil and floor also be implemented by this kind of stuff?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Safari or Firefox though? E.g. https://gist.github.com/martynchamberlin/0ec9c68d1d216f23d3c009576ae3ebce

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox. I don't know about Safari but it should work.

Comment: @rexblack, technically you can; `Floor(x) = Round(x - 0.5)` and `Ceiling(x) = Round(x + 0.5)`

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, there is not a native way in CSS to round (or ceil/floor) numbers.

However — you mentioned you are using Sass. I found a [small Sass library](https://gist.github.com/terkel/4373420) that can round, floor, and ceil numbers to a specified precision.

For example, if you had a had `94.546` you could use `decimal-floor(94.546, 2)` which would return `94.54`.

Unfortunately, this might not help if you have to use `calc()` to calculate on the fly with CSS. However, if you can pre-calculate the `width` and floor it with Sass it would fit your needs. A possible solution could be using `@media` queries as a way to set breakpoints and use those breakpoints in your Sass preprocessing.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not solve my problem. Thanks a lot for explaining this and your suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

## The `round()` CSS function

In [*CSS Values and Units Module Level 4*](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-values/#round-func), you can round your number or dimension however you want with **the `round()` CSS function**.

```
round(<rounding-strategy>, valueToRound, roundingInterval)
```

The optional `rounding-strategy` can be one of `up`, `down`, `nearest` (the default), and `to-zero`, which respectively correspond to `Math.ceil`, `Math.floor`, `Math.round`, and `Math.trunc` in Javascript.

#### Example

To resize a `<canvas>` element to *almost <sub>(“the rounding interval being [a CSS pixel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel), not a device pixel.”)</sub>* fit its parent element, preserving the canvas pixel aspect ratio of 1:1 (assuming `window.devicePixelRatio` is a natural number):

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    width: round(down, 100%, 1px);
    height: round(down, 100%, 1px);
}
```

#### Browser support

Currently [only ***Safari* and the latest version of *Firefox*** support this.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_round)

#### See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/round
- https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2513

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is a one-pixel rounding error related visual discrepancy, in most cases, you don't actually need to round. A relatively simple solution is to make one of your items take up all of the remaining space.

In a flex scenario, if you don't need your layout to wrap, you can even pick oen of your center items for the least noticeable effect possible.

```css
.some-block {
    width: calc( ( 100% / 11 ) - 9.09px );
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.some-block:nth-of-type(5) {
    // Will attempt to take the whole width, but its siblings refuse to shrink, so it'll just take every bit of remaining space.
    width: 100%;
}
```

Depending on your exact CSS case, the pixel substraction could potentially be avoided altogether by using paddings or margins and maybe an additional nested element. That way, the CSS `calc()` becomes irrelevant and it all could be done in Sass, which has much more powerful math tools and doesn't make the client work for calculations.

Also in a flex context, if your goal is just to make every element equal, you may not need calculations at all. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503227/how-to-make-flexbox-items-the-same-size/29503264) for details.

In a table, since cell widths are calculated left to right, a similar trick can be employed, but you'll have to give `width: 100%` to the *last* cell, since there's no concept of `flex-shrink` and column widths are decided left to right.

```css
.my-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-cell {
    width: calc( ( 100% / 11 ) - 9.09px );
}

.table-cell:last-of-type {
    // Will attempt to take the whole width, but since previous column widths have already been determined, it cannot grow any further than its allocated width plus any stray pixels.
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically generate your CSS, I created a small class to do simple functions like round(), ceil(), floor(), abs(), mod() and sign() -- it can be used to build complex calc rules which you can pass to each other as arguments. If you use "var(--my-variable)" as a parameter, the CSS variable will be used.
Note: it works best with raw numbers and has a utility function toUnit to convert to pixels (etc) at the end.

you can call it like so, jquery as an example to set the style:

```
 $('#my-element').css('width', `${cssHack.toUnit(cssHack.round(1000/3),'px')}`)
```

Below is the code for the class (es6, no dependencies):

```
class cssHack
{
    //primary used for dynamic css variables-- pass in 'var(--dynamic-height)'
    static toUnit(val,unit)
    {
        unit='1'+unit;
        return ` calc(${val} * ${unit}) `;
    }

    static round(val)
    {
        // the magic number below is the lowest possible integer, causing a "underflow" that happily results in a rounding error we can use for purposeful rounding.
        return ` calc(${val} * ${Number.MIN_VALUE} / ${Number.MIN_VALUE}) `;
    }

    static abs(val)
    {
        return ` max(${val}, calc(${val} * -1)) `;
    }

    static floor(val)
    {
        return cssHack.round(` calc(${val} - .5) `);
    }

    static ceil(val)
    {
        return cssHack.round( `calc(${val} + .5) `);
    }

    static sign(val)
    {   
        let n = ` min(${val},0) `; //if val is positive then n =0. otherwise n=val.
        let isNegative= ` min(${cssHack.ceil(cssHack.abs(n))},1) `;
        let p = ` max(${val},0) `; //if val is negative then n=0, otherwise n = val;
        let isPositive= ` min(${cssHack.ceil(cssHack.abs(p))},1) `;
        return ` calc(${isPositive} + calc(${isNegative} * -1)) `;
    }

    static mod(val, base)
    {
        let abs = cssHack.abs(val);
        let div = ` calc(${abs} / ${base})`;
        let dec = ` calc(${div} - ${cssHack.floor(div)})`;
        return cssHack.round(` calc(${dec} * ${base}) `);
    }
}
```

Comment: What may not be obvious here is that you can pass in other CSS variables and such. So what I do is use Observers to watch for size changes on objects and set custom CSS variables. Then, we can use these custom variables and pass them in to these functions ie: $('#ID').css('width',cssHack.round(cssHack.toUnit(cssHack.floor("calc( var(--window-width,'1024') / 3)' ,'px) 
So my observer or event I write to set --window-width at the body level when it changes. And my calc rule applies on the fly with no javascript at that point.

Answer (score -1):

cant you round with sass? since you already use it, try its round, floor and ceil methods:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#bounding-functions

(also in older versions of sass, with a different syntax though)