# Expression to get width as a fraction using calc()

Tags: css

I try to construct an expression for a variable line height depending on the width using `calc()`. The result should be a [**fraction without units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number). Is it possible?

To be more precise, I would like to get something like `line-height: 2;` when `200rem / width < 2` and `line-height: 1;` when `200rem / width > 2`

So, the above `200rem / width` should somehow evaluate to a plain fraction. It may be using `100wh` or similar. Please note that **we don't know the width**, we must use a variable!

For example the following:

```
li > a {
    line-height: calc(22px + (28 - 22) * ((100vw - 480px) / (3840 - 480)));
}
```

could do the job, but it evaluates to some pixels minus some width units instead of **plain fraction without any units** as I need.

Comment: Could you use a media query?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 No, my goal is to build something variable, not something conditional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css calc - round down with two decimal cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754542/css-calc-round-down-with-two-decimal-cases)

Comment: @04FS Thank you, but no. That round function does work only if you specify the number, it does't  do the math calculations.

Comment: @SorinGFS the main point was supposed to be this part, _"Unfortunately, there is not a native way in CSS to round (or ceil/floor) numbers."_ (SO's new phrasing for the "possible duplicate of" auto-comment is terrible IMHO.)

Comment: @04FS Yes, I studied that function, is useless IMHO, it rounds .. a given string :))

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to specify styles depending on properties of the screen (width, for example). I learned the hard way not to use `rem` units when specifying screen limits so I did these calculations assuming a 14px rem value. You may need to adjust for your needs.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1400) {
    body {
        line-height: 2;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1399) {
    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }
}
```

[Read here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for more on media queries

Comment: Please read the question, I don't want to solve a problem here, I;m curious if is possible to get a width variable in calc to result plain fraction.

Comment: @SorinGFS
CSS doesn't do variables (like that), so the short answer is no. If you want change styles dynamically you'll need to use JS to respond to changes in layout.

Comment: @isick [CSS supports variables/custom properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Those "variables" are not assignable at runtime. i.e., you can't store the width of an element into them (as asked in the question)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I disagree. For example: `calc(22px + (28 - 22) * ((100vw - 480px) / (3840 - 480)))` , but in this case it evaluates to some pixels minus width units. I want plain fraction.

Comment: @SorinGFS what is a "plain fraction"?

Comment: @isick A plain fraction is like: 1/3, 0.33 (without rem, px, or any other possible units)

Comment: @SorinGFS calc only does that under certain conditions `opacity: calc(1/3)` will give you an opacity value of 0.3. My understanding is the output is determined by the units of the input. If you want a number type, you may only use number or integer types in the calculation. Read more here:
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation

Comment: @isick Yes, for that we can use `100vw`, the example given in post is working without issues, except I need calc() function to evaluate to a plain fraction without units. For example (not related to our case) `20vw / 100vw` shoud evaluate to a plain fraction. I don't know if is possible, for that reason I asked the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
.test-class {
  font-size: 20px;
  $width: 100px;

  @if (200rem / $width > 2) {
    line-height: 1;
  } @else {
    line-height: 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Lol, how did you decide that the width is 100px? :)

Comment: This is not CSS - this is Sass - and it will not be executed by the browser; only the sass compiler at compile time.

Comment: @isick You wrong again, this is plain css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @isick I dod not mention any if anywhere, I have mentioned calc()

Comment: @SorinGFS I'm commenting on this answer submitted by ssc-hrep3... His answer uses Sass and would not work for your purposes.

Comment: @isick Then you shoud address to his nick, not mine.

Comment: @SorinGFS I didn't address it to anyone's username, I simply posted it as a response to his answer (not your question). As someone who's been on SO for 4 years, you should know how it works by now...

Comment: @isick I wasn't paying attention to your first comment, my bad. My last comment was for the comment when you said `There is no @if statement in CSS. That is Sass.` Sorry.

Comment: @SorinGFS You tagged your question with SASS, so an answer based on SASS should be valid. In this scenario, these 100px come from somewhere in your code at compile time. It was not absolutely clear, that you do want a runtime solution. It was also not clear what width stands for. I recommend you to clarify your question.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Ok, I remove the sass tag , but my question is cristal clear from the first phrase: `I try to construct an expression for a variable line height depending on the width using calc().`

Comment: It is not, as you do not describe what the width is and where you get it from. Each element has a width, the window has a width, a width could be a variable in compile time etc.