# CSS integer division in calc

Tags: css

Is there a way to have an integer division (like 5 / 2 = 2) in CSS? I wanna know how many elements of a set number of pixels there are in my rom and use this number for margins but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Read that already I was wondering if there was a trick or something.

Comment: share your real use case, there is a lof ot ways to achieve what you want but it's specific to each case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css calc - round down with two decimal cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754542/css-calc-round-down-with-two-decimal-cases)

Comment: I'd like a solution in vanilla CSS but it seems it's not possible.