# How to round the result of a calc() involving viewport dimensions in styled-components?

Tags: css, styled-components

I have a dynamically sized grid of square divs, each of which has a 
height and width of `calc(100vmin / ${props => props.gridSize })`;

This doesn't always divide evenly, so there gaps between the lines of some of my grid lines.

I don't seem have access to SASS/LESS helpers like `floor` or `ceil` (they are not included in `syled-components/polish` either). Plain javascript (`Math.floor`) doesn't seem to be an option either, since it doesn't know how to handle `vh` units. Is there any way to ensure a whole pixel number from the result of this `calc`?

[image]

Comment: I wanted to suggest using a modulo divison, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to exist in calc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435330/using-modulus-in-css-calc-function